# javascript foreach with mysterious variable

Tags: javascript, foreach

I am trying to understand what this javascript does and I am looking at foreach and okay, I am guessing name variable is coming from the array. I can verify that from console.log. I can also verify, although I have no idea where it's coming from, that i is 0,1,2.

Can someone please point me to right direction of where this variable 'i' is coming from and how forEach works?

```
    function getNames() {
       var length = 0
           , names = "";
       ['John', 'Susan', 'Joe'].forEach(function (name,i) {
          length = i + 1;
          names += name + ' '
        })

        return {
            length: length,
            names: names
        }
    }
    undefined
    console.log(getNames());
    Object {length: 3, names: "John Susan Joe "}
    undefined
```

Comment: Do you understand where `name` is coming from, and who is calling that `function(name, i) { … }` callback?

Comment: No, I guess I do not.. just guessing it's coming from array but not sure.. digging further and going to read all the comment here.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time in JS you see a function that you don't understand, google it on Mozilla Developer Network, like this "mdn forEach".  If the function has a `$` in it, you might look google it adding "jquery".  In this case, though, it is a builtin and so we look it up with mdn.  MDN is not the ultimate authority on Javascript, but it is a very good resource as it is maintained by Mozilla, known for their Firefox web browser.

From [MDN Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> **Summary** The forEach() method executes a provided function once per array element.
>
> **Syntax** `arr.forEach(callback[, thisArg])`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - `callback` Function to execute for each element, taking three arguments:
>
>   - `currentValue` The current element being processed in the array.
>   - `index`
>       The index of the current element being processed in the array.
>   - `array`
>       The array that forEach is being applied to.
> - `thisArg` Optional. Value to
>     use as `this` when executing callback.

You have `['John', 'Susan', 'Joe'].forEach(function (name,i)` so you will see that `forEach` is being called as a method on the `Array` `['John', 'Susan', 'Joe']`.  Here the argument to `forEach( )` is an anonymous function with two parameters `function(name,i){...}`.  This function is supplying the `callback` function mentioned in the docs. That supplied function will get called by `forEach` as many times as there are elements in the array.  The docs say we will get 3 parameters, and in JS the 3rd parameter in this case (the array being modified) is being ignored as the function is written to only take two parameters.

So, matching up the parameters in the provided function with the specification,  in this case `name` is going to be the current value from the array, and `i` the index number.

Note, though, that what to call the parameters in a `function(param1,param2)` is completely up to the developer.  When reading someone else's code, you have to match up what they called `param1` and `param2` with what the specification or documentation for that feature says.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate the answer as not only I understand what this is now(I also altered the variable name and i to something else to verify), but now I am gonna go onto developer.mozilla.org for more information and perhaps read some of these before hand.(these are like perl FAQ).. I accept this as an answer. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you look the [*docs*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) properly it tells

> The forEach() method executes a provided function once per array element.

ForEach takes a callback function which can take 3 parameters.

1) Current Value

2) Index of current value // which is 0,1,2

3) Array Itself.

So in following passes value of variables will be as bellow

```
1) name ==> 'john', i ==> index of 'john' which is 0
2) name ==> 'Susan', i ==> index of 'Susan' which is 1
3) name ==> 'Joe', i ==> index of 'Joe' which is 2
```

Answer (score 0):

How foreach works is it takes a function as its argument.  That function is then called for each element of the array with the following arguments function(current_value,current_index,original_array) for example you can do this.

```
var sumVal = 0,
    sumInd = 0,
    myArray = [2,4,6];

function sumValues(current){
  sumVal += current;
}

function sumIndexes(notGonnaUse,index,o_array){
  sumInd += index;
}

// the following is equivalent to calling sumValues three times
// sumValues(myArray[0], 0, myArray);
// sumValues(myArray[1], 1, myArray);
// sumValues(myArray[2], 2, myArray); 

myArray.foreach(sumValues);

// sumVal is now equal to 2+4+6=12

// the following is equivalent to calling sumIndexes three times
// sumIndexes(myArray[0], 0, myArray);
// sumIndexes(myArray[1], 1, myArray);
// sumIndexes(myArray[2], 2, myArray); 

myArray.foreach(sumIndexes);

// sumIndex is now equal to 0+1+2=2
```

In each case the function is passed all three arguments even though sumValues is defined to take only one argument.  The remaining arguments can still be accessed using the arguments object.
Internally the function is free to call the arguments whatever it wants.

In the previous example we used named functions to pass to foreach, but in your example an anonymous function was passed

```
function (name,i) {
  length = i + 1;
  names += name + ' '
}
```

This function sets

name = current value
i    = current index

it was also passed in the original array ['John', 'Susan', 'Joe']  as the third argument.  Since it wasn't used the programmer didn't bother naming this argument.  It can still be accessed however using arguments[2].